# HTML5 svg drag and drop - how to?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, svg

I'm trying to create a framework for HTML5-based adventure/point and click games, and I want to start with creating a way of dragging objects (from screen to hotspots or inventory, from inventory to hotspots, etc.), with svg representing both objects and hotspots (ie. completely transparent shapes there to detect hits). The idea is to drag the item, and allow it to drop only if the mouse is touching the hotspot.

I've run into some problems. Firstly, assigning a draggable attribute to `<svg>` or the testing circle didn't work. I tried putting it in a `<div>`, but while the drag event did register and fire, the ghost image didn't show like in the html5rocks demos. How can I fix the dragging?

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Minkovsky/vetVL/).

Comment: In what browser are you not seeing the drag image?  I see a drag image in Firefox 4.

Comment: Firefox. I did manage to get dragging to work with normal elements by adding dummy data to dataTransfer (thanks for _not_ telling me that, html5rocks). But dragging an SVG element still seems kinda iffy, and doesn't quite work all the time.